# Facing issue on changing App Language in Android 13 & 14

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-13, android-14

I set my android app local via

```
fun setSystemLocale(context: Context): Context {
        val locale = getCurrentLanguage().locale
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val configuration = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        context.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }
```

set app local work fine on lower versions(Below Android 13) but, on Android 13 & 14 Sometimes language change partially or sometimes language change does not reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes language is changed partially in Android 13 & 14.

I could find a solution in [android's developer doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages?hl=en#kotlin).

Here is a sample code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    val appLocale = when (languageCode) {
        "firstCode" -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("en")
        "secondCode" -> LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("ar")
    }
    // Call this on the main thread as it may require Activity.restart()
    AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
}
```

If you want to use this solution, **your appcompat version must be 1.6.0 or higher.**

Answer (score 0):

The provided code snippet addresses a potential cause of missing language resources in your app built using Android App Bundles (AAB) for Play Store publishing. Here's a breakdown of the code and its implications:

Code Explanation:

Gradle

```
android {
  //... removed for brevity
  bundle {
     language {
       enableSplit = false
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the API level 33 and above you should use: `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(localeListCompat)`

Full example:

```
    private fun updateLocaleConfiguration(configuration: Configuration, newLocale: Locale): Configuration {
        Locale.setDefault(newLocale)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
            val localeList = LocaleList(newLocale)
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)
            configuration.setLocales(localeList)

            // If Device is running Android 14
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                val android14OrAboveLocale = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(newLocale.language)
                AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(android14OrAboveLocale)
            }
        } else {
            configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
        }
        return configuration
    }
```